# Can't get Fastapi websocket and celery to play nice

Tags: fastapi

```
import asyncio

from fastapi import APIRouter, WebSocket

from app.sherlock import main
import asyncio
import billiard as multiprocessing
from queue import Empty
from celery import Celery
from fastapi import WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect


router = APIRouter()


@router.websocket_route("/{username}")
async def handles(websocket: WebSocket):
    username = websocket.path_params["username"]
    await websocket.accept()
    q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=main, args=(q, username))
    p.start()
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        try:
            q_result = q.get(block=False)
        except Empty:
            q_result = None
        if q_result:
            try:
                await websocket.send_json(q_result)
            except WebSocketDisconnect:
                p.terminate()
                break
        if not p.is_alive():
            try:
                await websocket.send_json(q_result)
                await websocket.close()
            except WebSocketDisconnect:
                p.terminate()
            finally:
                break
```

So this is what I have so far, a user inputs a username, which then the backend picks up, makes about 400 requests to different websites, and returns data. I used multithreading for that.

My issue is that when I host the site and have multiple users on it, the website drastically slows down. My thought is that I may need to use Celery for this but dont really know where to start. Does anyone have any ideas? let me know!

Comment: Celery is a tool for asynchronous processing (somewhat similar to fastapi's background task, but more fancy). Your performance degradation is likely caused by resource draining, spend some time logging and monitoring CPU usage, network I/O, memory and see where you're application's bottlenecks shift to, rinse and repeat. This will be a very awarding challenge.